# Crear elementos dinámicamente detrás de elementos creados dinámicamente (Js, Jquery, Html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvc

Es posible añadir elementos dinámicos detrás de un elemento creado dinámicamente? Me explico, he generado un elemento dinámico y ahora, me gustaría añadir otro elemento de forma dinámica. Pongo una imagen para que se entienda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta el momento, añadía lo elementos mediante jquery ".after", como muestra el código de la siguiente función:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            debugger
            var Id = (this.id).split("_")[1];
            var name = (this.id).split("_")[0];
            if (name == 'AddRow') {
                var uuid = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
                // var numItems = $('.rows').length
                var IdName = 'newRow_' + Id;
                var row = document.getElementById('rows');
                var text = replaceAll(row.innerHTML, 'IdName', uuid);
                $('#' + IdName).after(text);
            }
            else {

            }
        });
    });
```

Pero claro, al intentar aplicar este método en un elemento generado dinámicamente, aun a pesar de conocer el id del elemento al que apuntar, no genera el nuevo elemento puesto que este no existe en la vista estática

Un saludo, muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, si el problema parece trabalenguas, ¿podrías agregar mas código para entenderlo mejor?

Comment: Claro, disculpa, después de releerlo me he dado cuenta también de lo mal expresado que está.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método `.before()` para agregar un elemento antes de otro que hayas creado, te dejo un ejemplo con etiquetas `<span></span>`.

```js
let contador = 1;

$('#generar').click(function(){


$('#contenedor').append(`<span id="texto${contador}">Texto ingresado${contador} </span>`);

contador++
});

$('#generaA').click(function(){

  $('#texto1').before(`<span>Agregado antes </span>`);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="generar">Genera</button> <button id="generaA">Genera Antes</button>
<div id="contenedor"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias Vick Muñoz, conozco el mñetodo, pero no me refería a eso, me refiero a que $('#' + IdName) no reconoce ese id ya que no es estático si no dinñamico. Si no me equivoco, esa es la razón por la que no genera el elemento.

Comment: Debugueando la librería de jquery me dice que el elemento que encuentra es nulo, es decir, ninguno...

Comment: `$('#'+IdName)` no dejes espacios, si no lo interpreta como `("# juanito")` y no lo va a reconocer.

Answer (score 0):

Debugueando la librería de jquery.js veo que cuando ataco al id de un elemento estático, este es encontrado :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, al tratar de encontrar un elemento generado a través de su id, el elemento al que hace referencia es "null":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De igual forma me ha pasado anteriormente al intentar crear un evento para el tipo "botón", solo funcionaba con el elemento estático, por lo que he tenido que crear la siguiente función:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var Id = e.target.id.split("_")[1];
        if (e.target.id.split("_")[0] == 'AddRow') {
            elementAddRow(Id)
        } else if (e.target.id.split("_")[0] == 'DeleteRow') {
            elementDeleteRow(Id);
        }
    }, false);
```

Busco algo similar para la inserción de código de forma dinámica.

Un saludo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, no entiendo si es una respuesta o estas agregando información a tu pregunta o es otra pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad que la descripción está un poco liosa y no se entiende demasiado, así que voy a contesntar según creo que te puedo ayudar.

En primer caso, te aconsejo asignar un `id` a cada una de las filas. Esto simplemente se hace asignado el atributo id al igual que puedes asignar cualquier otro atributo.

Por otro lado, para saber a qué linea pertenece cada botón, te aconsejo que utilices los atributos personalizados. Estos se forman con el prefijo "data-" delante de un nombre que quieras darle (por ejemplo, `data-fila-id`). Más tarde, solo has de recuperar ese campo con la información. En tu caso, yo almacenaría el id de la fila a la que pertenecen para así poder recuperarla en cualquier momento. El hecho de que estén generadas dinámicamente no tiene ninguna influencia en que pueda recuperar un elemento: si está en la página, se puede recuperar por el id.

Con estas dos cosas sería tan sencillo como recuperar el `data-fila-id` del botón que se ha pulsado, recuperar la fila con el contenido de ese data, clonar o generar la nueva fila dinamicamente e incluirlo en la página con la función `after()` de jQuery.

Por si no te queda claro, te dejo aquí un pequeño ejemplo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .button {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 5px 10px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }

        .removeButton {
            background: red;
        }

        .addButton {
            background: green;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".removeButton").on("click", removeRow);
            $(".addButton").on("click", addRow);
        });

        function addRow(event) {
            var rowId = $(event.target).attr("data-row-id");
            var $row = $("#" + rowId);
            var $newRow = $row.clone(true, true);

            var newId = "row_" + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);

            $newRow.attr("id", newId);

            $newRow.find(".removeButton").attr("data-row-id", newId);
            $newRow.find(".addButton").attr("data-row-id", newId);
            $newRow.find("input").val("");

            $row.after($newRow);
        }

        function removeRow(event) {
            var rowId = $(event.target).attr("data-row-id");
            var $row = $("#" + rowId);

            $row.remove();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="agenda">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Telefono</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="row_1">
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
                <td><div class="removeButton button" data-row-id="row_1">-</div></td>
                <td><div class="addButton button" data-row-id="row_1">+</div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Aquí te lo pongo para que le eches un ojo cómo funciona.

https://jsfiddle.net/oh8624Lu/https://jsfiddle.net/oh8624Lu/